# Domain wildcard to custom IP using dnsmasq

Tags: macos, homestead, dnsmasq

I'm trying to set up my local web development environment to map all `.test` domains to `192.168.10.10` IP. The problem is that I find all the tutorials extremely confusing.

Here's what I did already:

1. I installed `dnsmasq` using Homebrew with `brew install dnsmasq` command.
2. I put `address=/.test/192.168.10.10` to `/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf`.

I'm not sure what to do with the resolver. I have an `/etc/resolv.conf` file containing `nameserver 172.20.10.1` (I don't know where it comes from) and then some tutorials say to create `/etc/resolver/test` file and putting `nameserver 127.0.0.1` there.

Here's where I'm lost. First of all, which resolver should I use? The `resolv.conf` file or `/etc/resolver/test`? If that's the latter one, should I edit out the `resolv.conf`? And also, should I put `nameserver 127.0.0.1` or `nameserver 192.168.10.10`? I don't understand if that's supposed to be the IP of my local machine (`127.0.0.1`) or my web dev machine (`192.168.10.10`).

Please help me to understand it better.

Comment: You haven't mentioned anything about `/etc/hosts`, do you have anything set in there? If you're trying to have `foobar.test` resolve properly you don't need the `.` before `test`.

Comment: It worked after restarting macOS.